# Mac terminal doesn't recognize ll command, only works with ls. How to fix it? Thanks

Tags: terminal

currently I am using my mac terminal for programming. I just want to display the files on terminal but ll does not work. It complained like this
$ -bash:ll:command not found.
Anybody could help me out there? Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

There is no ll command on a vanilla macOS installation. On some Linux distributions ll is an alias to ls.

```
$ which ll
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
    /bin/ls
```